# How to order sparse matrix and store the result

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a big sparse matrix:

```
> str(qtr_sim)
Formal class 'dsCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 7 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:32395981] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:28182] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 28181 28181
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:28181] "1000191" "1000404" "1000457" "1000541" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:28181] "1000191" "1000404" "1000457" "1000541" ...
  ..@ x       : num [1:32395981] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..@ uplo    : chr "U"
  ..@ factors : list()
```

The matrix contains values of cosine similarity - the numbers between 0 and 1.

An example of such a matrix, where A,...,E I will call **"products"**:

```
>A
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
     A    B    C   D    E
A 1.00 0.51 .    .   0.03
B 0.51 1.00 0.40 .   0.06
C .    0.40 1.00 0.1 0.05
D .    .    0.10 1.0 .   
E 0.03 0.06 0.05 .   1.00


> dput(A)
new("dgCMatrix"
    , i = c(0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 4L)
    , p = c(0L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 17L)
    , Dim = c(5L, 5L)
    , Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
    , x = c(1, 0.51, 0.03, 0.51, 1, 0.4, 0.06, 0.4, 1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 
1, 0.03, 0.06, 0.05, 1)
    , factors = list()
)
```

I need to find a fast way to obtain from matrix A two matrices B, C:

```
>B
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
            A       B       C       D       E     
  [1,]   1.00    1.00    1.00     1.0    1.00
  [2,]   0.51    0.51    0.40     0.1    0.06      
  [3,]   0.03    0.40    0.10       .    0.05
  [4,]      .    0.06    0.05       .    0.03   
  [5,]      .       .       .       .       .

>C
            A       B       C       D       E     
  [1,]      A       B       C       D       E
  [2,]      B       A       B       C       B      
  [3,]      E       C       D      NA       C
  [4,]     NA       E       E      NA       A   
  [5,]     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

There dosn't have to be "NA" but I use it in my code (see below).

I'm using this approach:

```
  B <- C <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))
  colnames(C) <- colnames(B) <- colnames(A)

  for (j in 1:nrow(A)){
    c <- A[ ,2, drop = F]
    posi <- colnames(c)

    d <- order(c, decreasing = T)
    mat <- c[d, ]

    if (which(names(mat) == posi) != 1){
      firstr <- mat[which(names(mat) == posi)]
      mat <- mat[-which(names(mat) == posi)]
      mat <- c(firstr,mat)
    } #this is because sometimes similarity of value 1 doesn't
      #only belong to one products and I need first row = column 
      #names !!!! The next product with similarity 1 should be 
      #in next row and so on.


    myNAs <- lapply(mat, function(x) which(x == 0))
    a <- as.numeric(which(myNAs == 1))
    names(mat)[a] <- NA
    C[,j] <- names(mat)
    B[,j] <- as.numeric(mat)
  }
```

But this approach is really slow. Note the original sparse matrix is much bigger then this example A.

How can I improve my approach?

Comment: You should probably turn the sparse matrix into a long-format data.table and work with that.

Comment: @Roland imagine you have ordinary matrix of 2 columns. One contains some numbers and the second one some names. And it is simple to order this matrix by column with numbers and that means the column with names will be also rearrange. And I want to store the column with ordered numbers in one matrix and the column with rearrange names in other. It's all because I have to provide matrix with IDs of most similar products to other products and also the values of this similarity. But thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, maybe this is of use:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(val = A@x, i = A@i + 1L, 
                 product = rownames(A)[A@i + 1L],
                 j = rep(rownames(A), diff(A@p)))
setorderv(DT, c("j", "val"), c(1L, -1L))
DT[, newi := seq_len(.N), by = j]

dcast(DT, newi ~ j, value.var = "val")
#   newi    A    B    C   D    E
#1:    1 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.0 1.00
#2:    2 0.51 0.51 0.40 0.1 0.06
#3:    3 0.03 0.40 0.10  NA 0.05
#4:    4   NA 0.06 0.05  NA 0.03
dcast(DT, newi ~ j, value.var = "product")
#   newi  A B C  D E
#1:    1  A B C  D E
#2:    2  B A B  C B
#3:    3  E C D NA C
#4:    4 NA E E NA A
```

Of course, the reshape could potentially create large dense objects, thereby exhausting your memory. If that is a problem, you'll need to reverse the first step and try creating a sparse matrix using `newi`, `j` and `val`.

Comment: that looks nice. Thank you. I will test it on data for which I have result. But can you please write some explenation of what are you doing? Like why 
`j = rep(rownames(A), diff(A@p)))` - I know what it does but I don't know how, because I'm not sure that I understand what `p`, in sparse matrix, means (I read help, but it didn't help). And also `seq_len(.N)` - does `.N` mean #rows of `DT` (or #obseravtion of `DT`)?

Comment: remark: if you have `'dsCMatrix'` sparse matrix `A`, you should first transform this matrix: `A <- as(A, "dgCMatrix")` or it does not work properly

Comment: `.N` refers to the number of rows in the groups defined in `by`. Regarding `p`: Look at `A@p`. There are 17 non-zero elements in your matrix. The first one is in column one, there are three values in that column, the fourth one is in column two, there are four values in that column, ... So, `p` defines in which column the values belong, but also gives you the cumulative count of values up to a specific column. By using `diff` I get the number of non-zero values in each column.