# swapping values in big sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, swap

I have a really big sparse matrix so I need some fast solution of my problem:

Let's `A` be some small sparse matrix (just for example):

```
> A
4 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
            A       B       C       D       E     
  [1,]      1       1       5       4       6
  [2,]     51       2      40       1       5       
  [3,]      3      40      10       .      50
  [4,]      .       6       3       .      30   

> dput(A)
new("dgCMatrix"
    , i = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L)
    , p = c(0L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 17L)
    , Dim = 4:5
    , Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
    , x = c(1, 51, 3, 1, 2, 40, 6, 5, 40, 10, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 50, 30)
    , factors = list()
)
```

And I need is the first row values == column position. Like this:

```
            A       B       C       D       E     
  [1,]      1       2       3       4       5
  [2,]     51       1      40       1       6      
  [3,]      3      40      10       .      50
  [4,]      .       6       5       .      30
```

So all I want is to swap the values. In this example I want to swap:

`A[1,2]` and `A[2,2]`

`A[1,3]` and `A[4,3]`

`A[1,5]` and `A[2,5]`

But I have really big sparse matrix, so I have to first find where `A[1,i] != i` and then find the row `which(A[,i] == i)` and swap them.

I tried this:

```
ROW <- A[1,]
  for (i in 1:ncol(ROW)){
    if (ROW[i] != i){ 
      a <- ROW[i]
      b <- A[which(A[,i] == i), i]

      p <- which(A[,i] == i)

      A[1,i] <- b
      A[p,i] <- a
    }
  }
```

It works but it's really slow. The original matrix I work with have 28182 rows and 28182 columns.

How can I improve my approach?

Please don't ask me why I need to do this weird thing. I just need it. You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116609/how-to-order-sparse-matrix-and-store-the-result/46118228?noredirect=1#comment79263070_46118228) and find out why I need it.

Comment: In your code, `p` may contain more than one positions.  What would you do in such cases?

Comment: @KotaMori this can't happen. The values in columns of `A` are product IDs and one product can be only once in one column.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you work with "dgTMatrix", where a matrix is represented by three vectors, `(i, j, x)`, which corresponds to row ids, col ids and cell values.

Your swapping operation can be conducted by using these vectors directly.

```
library(Matrix)
A <- new("dgCMatrix"
    , i = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
            2L, 3L)
    , p = c(0L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 17L)
    , Dim = 4:5
    , Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
    , x = c(1, 51, 3, 1, 2, 40, 6, 5, 40, 10, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 50, 30)
    , factors = list()
)


B <- as(A, "dgTMatrix")

flg1 <- (B@i == 0) & (B@j != (B@x-1))  # corresponds to `i`
val1 <- B@x[flg1] # corresponds to `a` 
col1 <- B@j[flg1] 

flg2 <- (B@j %in% col1) & (B@j == (B@x-1)) # corresponds to `p`
val2 <- B@x[flg2] # corresponds to `b`

B@x[flg1] <- val2
B@x[flg2] <- val1

B
```